# CSS works in IE11 but not in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I have CSS codes which is good at IE11 but seemingly not good in IE8. I already tried using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

but it didn't work fine. Margins, borders and the ribbon class is not working.
To add some info, here is the CSS:

```
body{
  background-image:url(images/bg4.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-size:100%;
}
.all{
    right: 100px;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    }
h2{
  text-align: center;
  color: #F1F2F4;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none; color: #EC5C93; 
}
.ribbon{
  background: rgba(200,200,200,.5);
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 19px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-bottom: 0;  
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.7); 
}
.ribbon:before{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #4E535B;
  border: 4px solid #cfd0d1;
  margin: 18px auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 2px #000, 0 1px 1px 1px #A7A8AB;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.login{
  background: #F1F2F4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #C5C5C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #36383C;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 40px 5px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.login:before{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #4E535B;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #CBCBCD;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.font{
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #191970;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p{
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #7B808A;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input{  
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #71747A;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
input:focus{
  outline: none;
}

button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  background: #0066FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:0;
  border-top: 1px solid #0066FF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0066FF, 0 2px 2px #0066FF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #21756A;
  margin-left:155px;
}
```

While the HTML is here:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Optis Appraisal System</title>
          <link href='login.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <script src="Plugins/placeholders.jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>   
    <div class="all">   
      <div class="ribbon"></div>
      <div class="login">       
           <br/><img src="images/optis3.jpg"/> <div class="font">Appraisal System</div>
          <p>Please login to start</p>    
          <form method="post" action="login.php">
                <table width=100%>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="login"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <center>
                <button name=commit>Login</button>
            </center>
          </form>
      </div>

        <footer>
            <center> 
                <font size="2" color="black"><br/>
                Developed by: <br/>
                anjomarc_topacio | mark.adriane | nica.dizon <br>
                Copyright 2014 &#169 Management Information System
                </font>
            </center>
        </footer>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this? I badly need your help. Thanks!

Comment: it'll be helpful if you can be bit more specific , which styles are not getting applied in ie8?

Comment: Margins, borders and the ribbon class is not working.

Comment: Right off the hop ie8 doesn't support rgba()... Switch it to solid hex color and then see what still isn't working. Box-shadow and border-radius are also out, unless you use something like CSS Pie: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll check if this will be solved if I changed rgba to hex value

Comment: Thank you! rgba to rgb conversion helped! I have another problem. Box-shadow isn't working. Any idea please?

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description. And you should do at least something to *isolate* the problem by reducing the page to a simpler case that still produces the issue. And PHP is not HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are two ways to handle it (css3 properties like box-shadow, border-radius won't be supported in ie8).
  1) you can use hacks for ie8  :
     To target Internet Explorer 8 and below in CSS, append “9” to the end of the style you want to apply.  e.g.

```
div {
  border: 2px solid #aaa; /* for all browsers */
  border: 2px solid #f009; /* IE8 and below - red border */
}

.element {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px\9; /* IE8 */
}
```

2) using conditional statements from within your HTML :

```
 <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  Your IE8 and below HTML code here.
  Perhaps importing a specific style sheet.
<![endif]-->
```

e.g :

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html>             <!--<![endif]-->
```

styles :

```
.element {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ie7 .element {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ie8 .element {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: hi! thanks but the conditional statements in html is not working. Also, margin, box-shadow and border-radius are not also working.

Comment: Conditional is a way to give styles specific to a browser without affecting others, margin should work with the hack i suggested and box-shadow , border-radius are css3 attributes which won't be supported in IE8. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For starters, IE8 does not support `border-radius` or `box-shadow`.

[caniuse.com is your friend.](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Answer (score 1):

if you are really looking for a alternative for css3 attributes in IE8 , you could probably use an image to give the curved corner effect and shadow, at the cost of increased bandwidth and messy code.
Other alternative is 
- http://css3pie.com/
- try  border-radius.htc can download the code from https://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius-demo.zip and test it.